# Storing What The User Draws and Using it Later

Tags: android, android-canvas

So far, in my app, a user can use brushes and different colors to draw any picture he likes and save it to his phone. I have also made a simple game where a plane flies. How can I combine these two apps. So, after the user draws an image. He presses save, and then it should make the picture a certain size and use that as the character in the game. Any help would be appreciated! I'm new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are saving the images, then you probably know where do they end up, so on the game part of the app, just load and scale it as per http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Only don't read them from resources, use [`BitmapFactory.decodeFile()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29) instead.

Ooor you can go

```
Bitmap bp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmpOptions), width, height, false);
```

where `width` and `height` are your 'certain size' and `path` is the path where you saved the image.

[`createScaledBitmap()` reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Right now, in my app the pictures saves in the users phone gallery. So, how can i access that image. Like I don't want to have the user save the picture in his gallery than upload into app. I want it so the user draws and it directly uploads into app. Is that possible? Many thanks.

Comment: @Baller Are you going to merge the two apps into one? Or do you want to keep them separate?

Comment: I want to merge them if possible.